# Scraper doesn't stop clicking on the next page button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to get some names and corresponding addresses displayed upon a search and the search keyword is "Saskatoon". However, the data, in this case, traverse multiple pages. My script almost does everything except for one thing.

1. It still runs even though there are no more pages to traverse. The last page also holds ">" sign for next page option and is not grayed out.

Here is the link: [Page_link](https://www.saskatoonrealtors.ca/web/SRAR/Find_A_REALTOR/SRAR/Find_an_Agent/Find_A_REALTOR_2.aspx?hkey=96d9da44-1d30-4c12-8c70-b3c495fe0610)

Search_keyword: `Saskatoon` (in the city/town field).

Here is what I've written:

```
from selenium import webdriver; import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("above_link")
time.sleep(3)

search_input = driver.find_element_by_id("cityField")
search_input.clear()
search_input.send_keys("Saskatoon")
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "›"))).click()
        time.sleep(2)
    except:
        break
driver.quit()
```

BTW, I've just taken out the name and address part form this script which I suppose is not relevant here. Thanks.

Comment: Well, how that condition might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `class` attribute of `>` button as on last page it is `"ng-scope disabled"` while on rest pages - `"ng-scope"`:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='ng-scope']/a[.='›']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thanks sir Andersson, for your answer. Plus one for this. It's always a great pleasure to be in contact with you. However,  for some reason it is not being able to click on the next page now, when i fit your locator within my script.

Comment: OK. Let me check

Comment: Oh, yeap, its class name of parent `li` :) Check updated

Comment: I never found your attempt to be fruitless. Btw, nowadays I'm a great fan of css selector. So, in you spare time plaese take a look if it is possible to create it using css selectors as well. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: Try `"li[class='ng-scope']>a[ng-click='setCurrent(pagination.current + 1)']"`

Comment: Yes, it works as it should. Thanks a lot once again.